# Forwarding Constructor with CRTP

Tags: c++, clone, crtp

I'm using a template class with CRTP to implement the clone pattern, with a second template parameter Base to allow for multiple levels of inheritance. I get a compiler error when I try to invoke the indirect base class's constructor.

```
class B
{
public:
    B() {} //trivial constructor
    virtual B* clone()=0;
};

template<class Base, class Derived>
class Clonable
    :public Base //weird, I know
{
public:
    virtual B* clone() {return new Derived(*this);}
};

class D1 : public Clonable<B, D1>
{
public:
    D1(int a); //non-trivial constructor. Different signature than B
};

class D2 : public Clonable<D1, D2>
{
public:
    D2(int a): D1(a) {} //compiler error here
}
```

The only solution I've come across so far is to use a variadic template constructor in Cloneable, but my compiler (VC++11) hasn't implemented them yet.

Comment: AFAIK your compiler doesn't have that either but an inherited constructor could be preferred to a variadic, perfect-forwarding constructor in this case. This would look like `using Base::Base;` in the `Clonable` definition. Just as a heads-up!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to let your cloning "middleman" class forward constructor arguments, or better (Luc Danton suggested this) use C++11 constructor inheritance.

So, it's easy to do this in C++11, but it's not so easy in C++03 or with a current compiler that doesn't yet support C++11 argument forwarding or constructor inheritance, such as Visual C++10.

One way to do that in C++03, using a helper argument forwarder class, is discussed in my old blog posting ["3 ways to mix in a generic cloning implementation"](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/cppx-3-ways-to-mix-in-a-generic-cloning-implementation/#middleman_base_class). Then the middleman (cloning implementation) class can look like this:

```
template< class Derived, class Base >
class WithCloningOf
    : public progrock::cppx::ConstructorArgForwarder< Base >
{
protected:
    virtual WithCloningOf* virtualClone() const
    {
        return new Derived( *static_cast< Derived const* >( this ) );
    }

public:
    template< class ArgPack >
    WithCloningOf( ArgPack const& args )
        : progrock::cppx::ConstructorArgForwarder< Base >( args )
    {}

    std::auto_ptr< Derived > clone() const
    {
        return std::auto_ptr< Derived >(
            static_cast< Derived* >( virtualClone() )
            );
    }
};
```

I discussed the C++03 compatible `ConstructorArgForwarder` in earlier blog posting; it can look like this:

```
template< typename Type >
class ConstructorArgForwarder
    : public Type
{
public:
    typedef Type        Base;

    // TODO: remove
    virtual ~ConstructorArgForwarder() {}

    ConstructorArgForwarder( EmptyArgPack const& )
        : Base()
    {}

    template< class T01 >
    ConstructorArgForwarder(
        ArgPack< T01 > const& args
        )
        : Base( args.a01 )
    {}

    template< class T01, class T02 >
    ConstructorArgForwarder(
        ArgPack< T01, T02 > const& args
        )
        : Base( args.a01, args.a02 )
    {}

    template< class T01, class T02, class T03 >
    ConstructorArgForwarder(
        ArgPack< T01, T02, T03 > const& args
        )
        : Base( args.a01, args.a02, args.a03 )
    {}

    // And more, up to max 12 arguments.
};
```

It in turn uses an argument pack class `ArgPack` (well OK, class template), which can look like this:

```
enum NoArg {};

template<
    class T01 = NoArg, class T02 = NoArg, class T03 = NoArg,
    class T04 = NoArg, class T05 = NoArg, class T06 = NoArg,
    class T07 = NoArg, class T08 = NoArg, class T09 = NoArg,
    class T10 = NoArg, class T11 = NoArg, class T12 = NoArg
    >
struct ArgPack;

template<
    >
struct ArgPack<
    NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg,
    NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg
    >
{};

typedef ArgPack<
    NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg,
    NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg
    >                                           EmptyArgPack;

inline ArgPack<> args() { return ArgPack<>(); }

template<
    class T01
    >
struct ArgPack<
    T01, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg,
    NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg, NoArg
    >
{
    T01 const&  a01;
    ArgPack( T01 const& v01 )
        : a01( v01 )
    {}
};

template< class T01 >
inline ArgPack< T01 >
args( T01 const& a01 )
{
    return ArgPack< T01 >( a01 );
}
```

Disclaimer: erors may just have sneaked in e.g. in copying the code from my blog. However, it worked at the time I posted about it, in May 2010.

Note: As I discuss at in the last of the two above blog postings, about cloning, there *three* main general ways to do it, and of these the simple *macro* beats the other two with good margin, for C++03. However, with C++11 the "middleman" approach you've chosen here seems better. The "sideways inheritance" via dominance is just complicated and inefficient, but if you are restricted to C++03, then do consider a simple macro!

Note 2: The last time I suggested doing the practical & sensible thing, I was heavily downvoted (presumably by Reddit kids). Since then, however, I have stopped caring about SO rep points, and in particular downvotes. So, happily, I can now again give good advice, just like in the old Usenet days, just ignoring them downvoter kids' mindless reaction to certain words. :-)

Comment: I'll probably end up using a macro, at least until I get a compiler with better C++11 support. I actually didn't even think of that, since I leapt at the opportunity to try out CRTP when my project started calling for it

Comment: I had spent 1~2 days to try the CRTP cloneable solution, didn't find a clear and easy way to do. Even it works as this answer described, I don't know if it is worth to do it like that. Maybe will also end up with manually create the 'clone' function sadly.