# C++ How can I allocate dynamic memory for a polymorphic type depending on user input?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Here's a few lines from my code:

```
class Base;
class DerivedA : public Base;
class DerivedB : public Base;
class DerivedC : public Base;

std::vector<Base*> vector_of_base;
vector_of_base.push_back(new Base);
vector_of_base.push_back(new DerivedA);
vector_of_base.push_back(new DerivedB);
vector_of_base.push_back(new DerivedC);

// input from the user
std::vector<std::size_t> user_defined_index;

std::vector<Base*> new_vector;
for(auto index: user_defined_index)
{
    // I have no idea if this will work as I expect
    Base *object = nullptr;
    object = vector_of_base.at(index);

    // compare the type of object to allocate the right thing
    if(typeid(object) == typeid(Base)
    {
        // allocate a new instance of Base
        // copying values from the previous instance (although
        // this is strictly speaking not necessary in my requirements)
        new_vector.push_back(new Base{object});
    }
    else if(typeid(object) == typeid(DerivedA))
    {
        new_vector.push_back(new DerivedA{object}); // ?
    }
    // etc ...
}
```

There is one immediate problem is that I have a significant number of `Derived*` types. (Somewhere around 20 - 30, and hence this produces a lot of duplicate code in one long `if-else if-else` statement.

However, I am not actually sure if the above code will actually work. Will the `typeid(object)` will always produce the value `typeid(Base)`, or will it produce the "expected" value. In other words, if `object` was allocated using `new DerivedA` then does the `typeid(object)` statement produce the same value as `typid(DerivedA)`?

The code above might not be that clear, so here is a summary of what it does:

- A `vector` is allocated with every possible type of `Base` and `Derived` type. Each of these types overloads a `GetName()` operator which returns a `std::string`.
- These strings are inserted into a graphical user interface. The user selects the quantity of each type required. (May be zero.)
- A new vector must be created, and it must contain objects allocated with `new`. The type of each object to be allocated is dictated by the users selection of quantity and order of each type from the GUI.

Hopefully that makes at least some sense?

Comment: You may want to check out `dynamic_cast` as opposed to those if statements https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: Sounds like you want the [clone idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148706/copying-a-polymorphic-object-in-c)

Comment: You probably want to use some kind of factory pattern.

Comment: @WestonMcNamara I thoght about potentially using it but I couldn't see exactly how that would be done - can you give any hint?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok I feared that might be the case. I will get my template patterns book out

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant the docs give fairly decent examples, but it would probably be something similar to `if (Base* base = dynamic_cast<Base*>(object)) {//push it back}`.


With `Base` being the class you're attempting to cast it to. dynamic cast returns a valid pointer to the casted class if the cast is successful, and if not it will return a null pointer, and the if statement will fail. (make sure you read through the docs fully so you dont make any mistakes while using it)

Comment: @WestonMcNamara I can see that would be a slight improvement, but it would still require a block of 20 `if` cases if there were 20 different possible `TYPE` to put inside the angled brackets of the `dynamic_cast<TYPE>`?

Comment: Yes it would unfortunately, this suggestion doesnt really solve that problem. It is more just a general suggestion for when you down/upcast pointers.

Comment: `if(dynamic_cast<Base*>(object))` will also give false positives because (almost*) all pointers to derived classes that publically inherit from `Base` can be successfully casted to  `Base*` pointers. (*exceptions include some virtual inheritance weirdness that probably doesn't apply)

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant You don't need a whole factory. If your goal is to display "class" to user and construct object of selected classes, the easiest way is probably to create some kind of `map<std::string, std::function<Base*()>>`, fill it with appropriate values, and then use it to construct the object. That a cheap factory that might be sufficient for you. You can use some template stuff to reduce the boilerplate code to fill that map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recall all the details of my original problem, but since the time when I posted this question I have learned that there is a standard design patterns solution for this type of problem:

- Clone Ideom (an example of a factory function)

To recap the important parts from the question:

- There is a vector which is initialized at the start of the program, and its job is to hold an instance of each type of object derived from a base class. It holds "prototypes" of each object.

```
std::vector<Base*> v;
v.push_back(new Derived); // ... repeated for each derived type
```

There is then a second vector which holds the same base class pointer type. This vector is populated (by user input) at *runtime* by data coming into the program. (In this case from user input, but it could equally have been from reading data from disk or a socket.)

```
std::vector<Base*> copies_of_v;
```

What we need to bridge these two things is a clone method defined for each derived class.

```
class Base
{

public:

    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
};
```

Which would be implemented like this...

```
class Derived : public Base
{

public:

    Base* clone() const override
    {
        return new Derived(*this); // use copy constructor to copy myself
    }

};
```

We use it like this: (Recall that `index` is some user input data which tells us which element to create.)

```
copies_of_v.push_back(v[index]->clone());
```

The hideous `if-else-elseif` block goes away. This is key because we no longer have to add a new `else if` case statement for each new derived type. Instead, we just implement a new `clone` function in each derived class.

- We have *polymorphic* clone (creation) behaviour

It works because each `clone` function knows internally what the type is which must be created and returned. Whereas, if this logic were to be external to the class (ie: part of the if-else-elseif block) then the type cannot be known except by inspecting the type as part of a block of logic. (if statement)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to shorten your code, you probably want this:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
    virtual void print() const { cout << "A" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    virtual void print() const override { cout << "B" << endl; }
};

vector<A *(*)()> vec;

template <typename T> void foo() {
    vec.push_back([]() -> A * { return new T; });
}

int main() {
    foo<A>();
    foo<B>();
    // Add more foo<T>()

    int i = 0;
    vec[i]()->print(); // prints A
    i = 1;
    vec[i]()->print(); // prints B

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP doesn't specify if they can modify the class code, or whether they have to use the Base and Derived classes as given. **IF** the OP is in control, this is a basic clone idiom:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define CLONE_CODE(T) \
std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const { return std::make_unique<T>(*this); } 

class Base
{
public:
    virtual CLONE_CODE(Base)
    virtual std::string type() const { return "Base"; };     
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:  
    CLONE_CODE(DerivedA)
    std::string type() const { return "DerivedA"; }
};

class DerivedB : public Base
{
public:
    CLONE_CODE(DerivedB)
    std::string type() const { return "DerivedB"; }
};
   
int main()
{
    using BasePtr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;
    using PtrVec = std::vector<BasePtr>;

    PtrVec vecSource;

    vecSource.push_back(std::make_unique<Base>());
    vecSource.push_back(std::make_unique<DerivedA>());
    vecSource.push_back(std::make_unique<DerivedB>());
    //etc

    std::vector<std::size_t> vecIndex = { 0,1,2,1,1 };

    PtrVec vecCopy;
    for (auto n: vecIndex)
         vecCopy.push_back(vecSource[n]->clone());
   
    //Check copied vector has the correct types
    for (auto& p : vecCopy)
        std::cout << p->type() << std::endl;
}
```

With the output:

```
Base
DerivedA
DerivedB
DerivedA
DerivedA
```

The code uses a macro which isn't great. Of course you can write the code long-hand for each derived class. There are template versions of this, involving an intermediate template class eg [Forwarding Constructor with CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520745/forwarding-constructor-with-crtp), but they get rather complex (for me anyway!).

NB.

- I've used std::unique_ptr to wrap the raw pointers.
- Assumes each class has a copy constructor available.

Comment: This looks very similar to something I was reading yesterday. Fortunately I am in control of those classes. I can edit their code and recompile them. I'm still investigating what the best solution might be but I think this is one possibility.